# rails route question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a search functionality which at a high level works like this.

1 - I have a Search model, controller with a search_set action and search views/partial to render the search.
2 - At the home page a serach form is loaded with an empty search object or a search object initialized with session[:search] (which contains user search preferences, zip code, proximity, sort order, per page etc). This form has a post(:put) action to search_set.

3 - When a registered user performs a set the params of the search form are collected and a search record is saved against that user. If a unregistered user performs a search then the search set action simply stores the params in the session[:search]. In either case, the search is executed with the given params and the results are displayed. At this point the url of in the location bar is something like..

http://localhost:3000/searches/search_set?stype=1

At this point if the user simply hits enter on the location bar, I get an error that says "No action responded to show" I am guessing because the URL contains search_set which uses a put method and even though I have a search_show (:get) action (which simply reruns the search in the session or saved in the database) does not get called.

How can I handle this situation where I can route a user hitting enter into the location bar to a get method?

If this does not explain the problem , please let me know I can share more details/code etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that if you created your own routes instead of using restful routes this would not be a problem. Without seeing what you have exactly this might help:

```
map.connect "/searches/", :controller => 'searches', :action => 'show'
```

While gets are preferable for searching (sharing/bookmarking urls etc), if you are saving the search to the server a post request is appropriate.

I am not sure this helps, but Thoughtbot posted a great article on searching a while back:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805369/search-by-quacking-like-activerecord